# wp_update_post() Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom code that will create automatically the menu and update the 'post' table to make my menu publish. Here is my code.

```
$test = array( 
array(
'menu-item-db-id' => 0,
'menu-item-object-id' => 2,
'menu-item-object' => 'category',
'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
'menu-item-type' => 'taxonomy',
'menu-item-title' => 'Rome',
'menu-item-url' => 'http://test.exmple.com/rome/',
'menu-item-target' => '',
'menu-item-classes' => '', 
'menu-item-xfn' => '',
'menu-item-description' => ''
)
);


if($item_ids = wp_save_nav_menu_items( 7, $test )) {
   $my_post = array (
    'ID' => $item_ids,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_name' => $item_ids
);
  wp_update_post($my_post);
}
```

The problem here is when calling the function wp_update_post, I got an error:

```
Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in      /home/lingfish/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1068

Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/lingfish/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 2790

Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/lingfish/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 633

Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/lingfish/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1068
```

However after loading the page and then when I refresh but commenting all the code except this:

```
$my_post = array (
     'ID' => $item_ids,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_name' => $item_ids
);
 wp_update_post($my_post);
```

It will work, I have the filling that after saving the menu items it will not created automatically on the post table that's why when calling the wp_update_post there is no result. Do you have other solution so I can update the field post_status to publish so that my menu will be visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't throw in Array's to wp_update_post. You have to loop trough $item_ids and use the string values instead. Example;

```
if($item_ids = wp_save_nav_menu_items( 7, $test )) {

  foreach( $item_ids AS $single_item_id ) {

    $my_post = array (
     'ID' => $single_item_id,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_name' => $single_item_id
    );

    wp_update_post($my_post);

  }

}
```

Comment: You should extend your answer, it's easy to misunderstand.

Comment: You can, but than this is the wrong array setup. Every item in the array should have it's own key elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_post = array (
     'ID' => $item_ids,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
          'post_name' => $item_ids
);
wp_update_post($my_post);
```

the problem is line: `post_name' => $item_ids`
wp wants there a STRING, and you gave it an array.
loop through the ID's abnd change them one by one.